# Checking the contents of a LINQ query that is being added to

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a LINQ query that needs to check on the contents before adding something from the list, so what I have is this

```
var foo = (from f in list1
     from p in list1.list2
     from m in p.Bar
     let t = m.Type
     let c = someMethod(t)
     where c.Type == type && !foo.Contains(p)
     select p).ToList();
```

the !foo.Contains(p) is not allowed, so is there a way of checking the query as it goes along or before the ToList() should I just add Distinct() to do the same as the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to access the query as it is being built in the manner you are doing.  If you want to ensure that a particular value only appears once in the output then `Distinct` is the best approach

Comment: I thought that would be the case, just didn't know if there was some automatic LINQ way of doing it within the query